# docx4j Couldn't get [Content_Types].xml from ZipFile

Tags: ms-word, jaxb, docx4j

I have been googling and trying various things such as placing a jaxb.properties file into my web2 folder to specify eclipselink but not having any luck at all.

I can run from eclipse simple code

```
String inputfilepath = "mywordfile.docx";

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
MainDocumentPart main = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
```

But when it runs under jboss (same jdk, old version of jboss) I get

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException:
Couldn't get [Content_Types].xml from ZipFile
```

and I cant figure out an easy way to fix it.  Most googling suggests changing the implementation of jaxb - but I am not marshalling my own classes so it doesnt make sense (nor have my attempts worked).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use EclipseLink/MOXy JAXB (as opposed to the Sun/Oracle version in the JDK or the reference implementation), you need:

1. the relevant EclipseLink jars
2. docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext-3.0.0.jar (which just contains the jaxb.properties files)

The jaxb.properties files just say:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

If you are using maven, you'll just need to add:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
<artifactId>docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When you start docx4j, the log output will tell you which JAXB it is using.

Comment: great it was the docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext-3.0.0.jar I was missing, works now - thanks !!!